# FFT Algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, signal-processing

I am writing an FFT algorithm in Javascript and the algorithm that I am using is not giving the correct answer. I thought that I would see if anyone could spot the problem for me.

I tried using some code I found other places and the standard recursive method, but javascript won't work with algorithms like that because it needs callbacks to ensure that everything is being done in the proper order.

I developed a simple algorithm to separate the even and odds and then do the math, but it is giving flawed answers. The first for loop just does the initial even and odd separation. The second for loop builds on that to separate the even and odds at every level. Finally, the final loop does the math.

The output seems to be close for low frequency data, but is off for medium stuff. I think that I have an index wrong somewhere.

Thanks

```
    var Num=Object.keys(window[dataid].Solution_real).length;                                                       //  \
    var twopow=Math.pow(2,Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num)));                                                               //  \
    for (var a=Num; a<twopow; a++) {window[dataid].Solution_real['0-'+a]=0; window[dataid].Solution_imag['0-'+a]=0; }// \
    FFT[Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num))]={};                                                                              //  \
    FFT[Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num))]['r']=window[dataid].Solution_real;                                               //  \
    FFT[Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num))]['i']=window[dataid].Solution_imag;                                               //  \
    var hN=parseInt(Big(twopow).div(Big(2)));                                                                       //  \
    var a=Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num));                                                                                //  \
    var Top=Math.ceil(Math.log2(twopow));                                                                           //  \
    FFT[a]={};  FFT[a][0]={};   FFT[a][1]={};                                                                       //  \
    FFT[a][0]['r']={};  FFT[a][0]['i']={};  FFT[a][1]['r']={};  FFT[a][1]['i']={};                                  //  \
    for (var i=0; i<hN; ++i)                                                                                        //  \
    {   var doubp=parseInt(Big(2).times(Big(i)).plus(Big(1)));                                                      //  \
        var doub=parseInt(Big(2).times(Big(i)));                                                                    //  \
        var key0=0+'-'+i; var key1=0+'-'+doub;  var key2=0+'-'+doubp;                                               //  \
        FFT[a][0]['r'][key0]=window[dataid].Solution_real[key1];                                                    //  \
        FFT[a][0]['i'][key0]=window[dataid].Solution_imag[key1];                                                    //  \
        FFT[a][1]['r'][key0]=window[dataid].Solution_real[key2];                                                    //  \
        FFT[a][1]['i'][key0]=window[dataid].Solution_imag[key2];                                                    //  \
    }                                                                                                               //  \
    counter=4;                                                                                                      //  \
    for (var a=Math.ceil(Math.log2(Num))-1; a>0; a--)                                                               //  \
    {   FFT[a]={};                                                                                                  //  \
        var Num=Object.keys(FFT[parseInt(a)+1][0]['r']).length;                                                     //  \
        var hN=parseInt(Big(Num).div(Big(2)));                                                                      //  \
        for (var b=0; b<counter; b=parseInt(Big(b).plus(Big(2))))                                                   //  \
        {   var c=parseInt(b)+1;                                                                                    //  \
            FFT[a][b]={};   FFT[a][c]={};                                                                           //  \
            FFT[a][b]['r']={};  FFT[a][b]['i']={};      FFT[a][c]['r']={};      FFT[a][c]['i']={};                  //  \
            for (var i=0; i<hN; ++i)                                                                                //  \
            {   var doubp=parseInt(Big(2).times(Big(i)).plus(Big(1)));                                              //  \
                var doub=parseInt(Big(2).times(Big(i)));                                                            //  \
                var key0=0+'-'+i; var key1=0+'-'+doub;  var key2=0+'-'+doubp;                                       //  \
                FFT[a][b]['r'][key0]=FFT[a+1][Math.floor(b/2)]['r'][key1];                                          //  \
                FFT[a][b]['i'][key0]=FFT[a+1][Math.floor(b/2)]['i'][key1];                                          //  \
                FFT[a][c]['r'][key0]=FFT[a+1][Math.floor(b/2)]['r'][key2];                                          //  \
                FFT[a][c]['i'][key0]=FFT[a+1][Math.floor(b/2)]['i'][key2];                                          //  \
            }                                                                                                       //  \
        }                                                                                                           //  \
        counter=parseInt(Big(counter).times(Big(2)));                                                               //  \
    }                                                                                                               //  \
    var Num=Object.keys(FFT['2']).length;                                                                           //  \
    var r=-2*Math.PI;                                                                                               //  \
    for (var a=1; a<=Top; a++)                                                                                      //  \
    {   var Num1=Object.keys(FFT[a]).length;                                                                        //  \
        if (a==Top)                                                                                                 //  \
        {   FFT[parseInt(a)+1]={};                                                                                  //  \
            FFT[parseInt(a)+1][0]={}; FFT[parseInt(a)+1][0]['r']={};    FFT[parseInt(a)+1][0]['i']={};}             //  \
        for (var b=0; b<Num1/2; b++)                                                                                //  \
        {   var Num2=Object.keys(FFT[a][0]['r']).length;                                                            //  \
            for (var k=0; k<Num2; ++k)                                                                              //  \
            {   var k1=0+'-'+k;                                                                                     //  \
                var k2=0+'-'+parseInt(Big(k).plus(Big(Num2)));                                                      //  \
                var p=k/twopow;                                                                                     //  \
                var t=r*p;                                                                                          //  \
                var t2=Math.floor(Big(b).times(2));                                                                 //  \
                var t2p=Math.floor(Big(b).times(2).plus(Big(1)));                                                   //  \
                FFT[parseInt(a)+1][b]['r'][k1]=FFT[a][t2]['r'][k1]+FFT[a][t2p]['r'][k1]*Math.cos(t)-FFT[a][t2p]['i'][k1]*Math.sin(t);// \
                FFT[parseInt(a)+1][b]['i'][k1]=FFT[a][t2]['r'][k1]+FFT[a][t2p]['r'][k1]*Math.sin(t)+FFT[a][t2p]['i'][k1]*Math.cos(t);// \
                FFT[parseInt(a)+1][b]['r'][k2]=FFT[a][t2]['r'][k1]-FFT[a][t2p]['r'][k1]*Math.cos(t)+FFT[a][t2p]['i'][k1]*Math.sin(t);// \
                FFT[parseInt(a)+1][b]['i'][k2]=FFT[a][t2]['r'][k1]-FFT[a][t2p]['r'][k1]*Math.sin(t)-FFT[a][t2p]['i'][k1]*Math.cos(t);// \
            }                                                                                                       //  \
        }                                                                                                           //  \
    }                                                                                                               //  \
```

Comment: [numericjs](http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html) has FFT but is light on documentation.